# Google Cloud Storage returning 400 bad request without reason in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-storage, httparty

I am using the HTTParty gem in a Ruby on Rails app to make requests to my Google Cloud Storage bucket. Google returns a status code of 400 saying 'Bad Request' but does not give a reason for the error.  I have verified that the authorization is not the problem.  Here is my code:

```
module Google
  class Client
    include HTTParty
    base_uri "https://www.googleapis.com"

    def get_pics
     self.class.get("/storage/v1/b/bucket-name/o?key=<%= ENV['GOOGLE_KEY'] %>")
    end

  end
end
```

Then in the controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    response = Google::Client.new.get_pics
  end
end
```

Here is the response I am getting:

```
#<HTTParty::Response:0x7f8826f71268 parsed_response="<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY 
BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\" TEXT=\"#000000\">\n<H1>Bad Request</H1>\n<H2>Error 400</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n", @response=#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 
400 Bad Request readbody=true>, @headers={"content-type"=>["text/html; 
charset=UTF-8"], "content-length"=>["145"], "date"=>["Thu, 12 Nov 2015 
04:02:14 GMT"], "expires"=>["Thu, 12 Nov 2015 04:02:14 GMT"], 
"cache-control"=>["private, max-age=0"], "x-content-type-options"=>
["nosniff"], "x-frame-options"=>["SAMEORIGIN"], "x-xss-protection"=>["1; mode=block"], 
"server"=>["GSE"], "alternate-protocol"=>["443:quic,p=1"], 
"alt-svc"=>["quic=\":443\"; p=\"1\"; ma=604800"], "connection"=>["close"]}>
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-status

Answer (score 1):

This could be a lot of things, but the most likely reason is that your key is invalid. The most common reason that your key is invalid is that you are accidentally using the "key ID" of a service account and not an actual "API key" (they're easy to confuse).

To generate an API key, head to http://console.developers.google.com, open the toolbar, choose "API Manager", then choose the "Credentials" page. Ignore everything under the "Service account keys" section, even if it says "Key ID". Those are service account keys.

Instead, click "new credentials" and choose "API key". Choose "Server Key" or "Browser Key" in the popup (server key if you're gonna use it from your rails server, browser if it runs client side). Now, try using that new key.